# How can I search users in Active Directory based on surname and first name?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directorysearcher

I'm trying to search for users in AD with their surname (`sn`) and first name (`givenName`) using `DirectorySearcher` in .NET.

I can find a user based on `sAMAccountname` with this code:

```
 DirectorySearcher searcher1 = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
 searcher1.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountname={0}))",aLogin);

 SearchResult results1;
 results1 = searcher1.FindOne();
```

But when I try to do it with `givenName` and `sn`:

```
DirectorySearcher searcher1 = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
searcher1.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenname={0})(sn={1})", aName, aSName);

SearchResultCollection results1;
results1 = searcher1.FindAll();
```

It doesn't work; the message says "Invalid Filter";
Can I not filter based on `givenName` and `sn`?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I find this question generically useful without the specific typo issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing a closing parentheses in your filter.  Try:

```
searcher1.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenname={0})(sn={1}))", aName, aSName);
```

Answer (score 32):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, you could also make use of the `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce" and a last name (Surname) of "Miller"
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.GivenName = "Bruce";
qbeUser.Surname = "Miller";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20150118102648/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: Where, in this example, can you specify the AD connection string - username/password etc?

Comment: @PandaWood: the `PrincipalContext` has several overloaded constructors to support this

Answer (score 0):

No way this is an error..

I forgot a `)`